# Cannot insert information in MySQL

Tags: server, permissions, java, mysql

I am trying to insert information locally in a database with I program that is codified in Java but I am not being able to. My guess is that it is somehow related to user permissions, even though I do not know what I should do aside from what I already have. My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS. My actions have been as follows:

1. I open a Command Line Interface window and get in MySQL via

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   ```

Then I type in the password for root and get inside.

2. I set as `data` the database that has to be used with

   > use_data;
3. I create a new user with

   ```
   CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw';
   ```
4. I give the user all the required privileges to write information, regardless of the IP that would be used:

   ```
   GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

   GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

   GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'user'@'linux' IDENTIFIED BY 'passw' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `data` . * TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `data` . * TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `data` . * TO 'user'@'linux' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ```
5. I refresh the privileges by using `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
6. Yet when I try to access the database to insert information I get the following exception:

   ```
   Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.StackOverflowError
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
   ```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong not to obtain connection between my Java code and the database?

UPDATE: The part of the code where the exception is being thrown is in the method getConnection, when I try to access the database.

```
@Override
    public void openDBConnection() throws Exception {
        //this method establish a database connection
        try {
            // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
            Class.forName(driver);

            String connection = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + dbname + "?"
                    + "user=" + user + "&password=" + passwd + "&useSSL=false"; 
            System.out.println(connection);

            // Setup the connection with the DB
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + dbname + "?"
                    + "user=" + user + "&password=" + passwd + "&useSSL=false");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the problem lies in the definition of the jdbc driver.  Could you provide the lines of code leading to such exception?

Comment: I just added the code now. I don not think it is related to the JDBC connector because I have executed an example (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html) and it was sucessful, with no JDBC or MySQL issues.

Comment: java.lang.StackOverflowError and your stack trace repeats forever, there is a problem here... This question is about programming and will be handled better on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: I am not a java specialist but I read from the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) thay you need to register/load the required driver.  Did you do that?

Comment: I did that in the line Class.forName(driver), where driver is "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver". In any case I tried uploading explicitly like Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); and it does not work. It should not require to restart the whole system, should it?

Answer (score 0):

Privileges assigned through GRANT option do not need FLUSH PRIVILEGES to take effect - MySQL server will notice these changes and reload the grant tables immediately.

SO please give the required privileges and test is again. please do not run the "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

If you modify the grant tables directly using statements such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE, your changes have no effect on privilege checking until you either restart the server or tell it to reload the tables. If you change the grant tables directly but forget to reload them, your changes have no effect until you restart the server. This may leave you wondering why your changes seem to make no difference!
To tell the server to reload the grant tables, perform a flush-privileges operation. This can be done by issuing a FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement or by executing a mysqladmin flush-privileges or mysqladmin reload command.
If you modify the grant tables indirectly using account-management statements such as GRANT, REVOKE, SET PASSWORD, or RENAME USER, the server notices these changes and loads the grant tables into memory again immediately.

Comment: The question is a programming question, not a problem with authentication.

Comment: Actually, any help is useful. Unfortunately, I gave the needed provileges without flushing aferwards and the error persists.